# How to extend the button for a custom solution Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

Hi How I can extend in View the button for a custom solution?

I wont extend this:

....

```
 <Button BackgroundColor="#388fee" BorderColor="#388fee" BorderRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
                Command="{Binding CheckinShareCommand}" Margin="0,16">
            <Button.Image>
                <FileImageSource File="googlemap_view_share_button.png" />
            </Button.Image>
        </Button>
```

....

This is my custom solution.

When you press an image it magnifies it

public class CustomImage : Image
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(p => p.Command, null);
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
        }

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomImage, object>(p => p.CommandParameter, null);
    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    private ICommand TransitionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                this.AnchorX = 0.48;
                this.AnchorY = 0.48;
                await this.ScaleTo(2.8, 50, Easing.Linear);
                await Task.Delay(100);
                await this.ScaleTo(1, 50, Easing.Linear);
                if (Command != null)
                {
                    Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public CustomImage()
    {
        Initialize();
    }


    public void Initialize()
    {
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
        {
            Command = TransitionCommand
        });
```

....

Comment: Are you want magnifies effect on your button press?

Comment: yes, when I press button I want magnifies effect

Comment: Look at my answer hope its help you !!!

Comment: Thank you again :)

Comment: @ZiyadGodil Can I use this code to Image
example to this code, no use CommandParameter?
`<local:AnimatedImage CommandParameter="{Binding Position.From}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="googlemap_view_profil.png" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="16,24,16,0" />`

Comment: Are you mean using CommandParamedter in CustomButton?

Comment: You can also using this code for Image and you need to create custom property for CommandParameter

Comment: I would like to use this code below
`public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton() : base()
    {
        const int _animationTime = 10;
        Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var btn = (CustomButton)sender;
                await btn.ScaleTo(1.2, _animationTime);
                await btn.ScaleTo(1, _animationTime);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Track();
            }
        };

    }
}`

Comment: I am not getting you want you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want magnifies Image when you pressing on it Try Below Code :

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton() : base()
    {
        const int _animationTime = 10;
        Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var btn = (CustomButton)sender;
                await btn.ScaleTo(1.2, _animationTime);
                await btn.ScaleTo(1, _animationTime);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Track();
            }
        };

    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<userControls:CustomButton BackgroundColor="#388fee" BorderColor="#388fee" BorderRadius="25" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"
                Command="{Binding CheckinShareCommand}" Margin="0,16">
            <Button.Image>
                <FileImageSource File="googlemap_view_share_button.png" />
            </Button.Image>
        </userControls:CustomButton>
```

**Don't Forget to put this line in header**

```
xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.UserControls"
```